# how can perform a task in bg on android 12+ in react native?

Tags: react-native

Using react-native-background-actions when I am trying to perform some task in bg .its runs smoothly. but when Android 12+ comes into the picture. it failed it can`t be called outside the app. means it does not work in the background. is it possible to run background in Android 12+?

react native bg task problem

Answer (score 0):

**React Native background processing**

According to Android docs though, it’s pretty non-deterministic for how long it will stay alive, as soon as your app enters the background, be ready for the app execution to end at any moment

if we have some simple forever timer like this which you’ve launched in your app’s saga or thunk

For detail please visit the below link

[Visit link](https://codeburst.io/the-definitive-guide-to-react-native-background-processing-51df02540433)